# how to restrict method access based on oauth scopes in spring-rest-oauth?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

how to restrict access to methods based on scopes?
For example, in the below curl, I get access token that has only scope of "read". That is, user has authorized the client application with read only access to resources

`curl -X POST -vu clientapp:12334 http://localhost:9001/oauth/token -H "Accept: application/json" -d "password=spring&username=roy&grant_type=password&scope=read"`

But Note client is registered with auth server for two scopes - `read and write`.

Now, imagine the resource server has two endpoints

`/users/update` - this endpoint is a POST request. This should be exposed only if "write" scope is approved by the user.

`users/getInfo` - this endpoint is a GET request. This should be exposed because the user has granted client access with read scope

My question is how we control these access at method levels

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";

    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/update",  method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public UserProfile update(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {

          ///update userProfile 
         return userProfile;
    }

      @RequestMapping("/getInfo",  method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public UserProfile getProfile(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {

            //get the userData from database
            return userProfile;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to annotate methods with scopes: eg

```
  @scope("read")
   @RequestMapping("/getInfo",  method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public UserProfile getProfile(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {

            //get the userData from database
            return userProfile;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Spring Security OAuth has its own expression e.g. #oauth2.clientHasRole, #oauth2.clientHasAnyRole, #oauth2.hasScope

```
@PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('write')")
public void create(Contact contact);
```

Reference :

http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/expression/OAuth2SecurityExpressionMethods.html

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#el-access